# Application crashes when I open a new activity

Tags: java, android

So I have previously asked this question, but I did not include all of the necessary information on the crash. So, whenever I try to open this activity, my app crashes. 
my method of opening the application:

```
public void openGallery(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PhotoGallery.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

the crash log:

```
03-15 19:02:18.525 20081-20081/com.example.ayden.dielconstruction E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.ayden.dielconstruction, PID: 20081
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ayden.dielconstruction/com.example.ayden.dielconstruction.PhotoGallery}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
                                                                                    at com.example.ayden.dielconstruction.PhotoGallery.onCreate(PhotoGallery.java:11)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                                    at com.example.ayden.dielconstruction.PhotoGallery.onCreate(PhotoGallery.java:11) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                                    at com.example.ayden.dielconstruction.PhotoGallery.onCreate(PhotoGallery.java:11) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 201326604 byte allocation with 1944106 free bytes and 61MB until OOM
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
                                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:136)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
                                                                                    at com.example.ayden.dielconstruction.PhotoGallery.onCreate(PhotoGallery.java:11) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

the photogallery xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:scrollbars="none" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/project1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/project2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please paste your PhotoGallery activity's  layout xml file .

Comment: clue is here: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Answer (score 3):

Clearly you have an [out of memory error](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) when loading the image.

> Caused by: **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError**: Failed to allocate a 201326604 byte allocation with 1944106 free bytes and 61MB until OOM

You should probably look at the size of your images, they may well be unreasonably large for use in a mobile application.

As a general rule, you should start at the top of the stack trace and go down **Caused by**'s until one looks familiar.  If none do, read up on the one at the bottom the exception message, as that's the "root" cause.