# Fatal Exception while running android studio project caused by OutOfMemoryException

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I have recently added a button that allows me to go to google maps, after doing this none of my other buttons are working and the error message below is now showing. The button that brings up the map works but the other buttons don't now work.

Error that is appearing on my android monitor.

```
    04-19 14:06:31.004 11816-11816/com.example.matthew.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.matthew.myapp, PID: 11816
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 54859872 byte allocation with 1901032 free bytes and 1856KB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1031)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
at com.example.matthew.myapp.LineUpActivity.onCreate(LineUpActivity.java:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is my LineUpActivity class

```
 package com.example.matthew.myapp;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
 import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.View;

public class LineUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lineup);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: are you setting an image anywhere? Because you get an OOM Exception, so I gues you set a drawable that is too large....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio

Comment: You're trying to load nearly 55 MB in memory, while you have less than 2 MB....

Comment: I am setting a background image, but the file size is only 183kb.

Comment: You said it: `the file size`. But, when **uncompressed**, the size is `X * Y * 4 bytes`.

Answer (score 3):

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Add this in manifest file

This will allocate large heap for your app.

Answer (score 1):

I think The problem was caused by the Google Play service

change it to a specific library.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87
```

Comment: Where would I implement this ?

Comment: refere here [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Answer (score 1):

check your layout file activity_lineup.xml. I think you are loading a large size image as from res/drawable/ or somewhere in some of your view of that layout file.
below log clearly says this:

```
OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 54859872 byte 
...
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
...
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
```

so your activity is not able to launch because of outOfMemory exception.

Answer (score 1):

Use android:largeHeap="true" in application tag of manifest and Use Glide or Universal Image loader to load background or high size images