# setOnClickListener get OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I try calling an onClickListener for a button, but it is not working. Everytime when I tried to click on "Create Account" button, it does not direct me to register page, instead, it forcibly exit. I've looked into many posts, but I still didn't get the solution. Can anyone help me, please...

Here is the register.java

```
package ezms.ezms;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn_SignIn, btn_Reg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("EzMS - Online Store");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        btn_SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_SignIn);
        btn_SignIn.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_Reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Reg);
        btn_Reg.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn_SignIn:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, register_acc.class));
                break;

            case R.id.btn_Reg:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, register_acc.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is activity_register.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/banner"
    tools:context="ezms.ezms.register">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:id="@+id/btn_SignIn"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="95dp"
        android:background="#27468D"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create Account"
        android:id="@+id/btn_Reg"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_SignIn"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn_SignIn"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#27468D"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are the errors...

```
05-05 00:16:18.862 16596-16596/ezms.ezms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ezms.ezms, PID: 16596
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 95976012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 38MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:655)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:488)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:978)
at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:3016)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2711)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2597)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:348)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:751)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:102)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)   
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1030)
at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:729)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
at ezms.ezms.register_acc.onCreate(register_acc.java:18)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2415)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2524)         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1419)              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                         
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Comment: "   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 95976012 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 38MB until OOM" shows you are getting out of memory ; not null pointer

Comment: If you are using AVD, may be you need to increase RAM size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Comment: are you displaying an image somewhere? could be the image is too large

Comment: I think the problem is @drawable/banner image

Comment: @KrupalShah was just about to say that too till you beat me to it :P. It might be that even though you are trying to use a "banner" like image, the image is actually quite big and when trying to load it you get the OOM. Try testing it by adding some other image, any kind of image that is smaller. Run it. And see if you can actually continue to the new Activity or still get the OOM error. Just set by steps to get to the bottom of it :)

Comment: It could be an image in register_acc.class too

Comment: Thanks guys, I just adjust the image size, and it works well now...Really appreciated for the helps