# Genymotion: "Unfortunately <app> has stopped"

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I've created an application in React Native that works fine in iOS. I've copied the code over to the Android portion of it, and separated out the platform-specific components. When I hit a certain component, the app crashes with an "Unfortunately  has stopped".

There are no logs, no error in the console, nothing. What do I look for and where can I look? Logs? Somewhere in code?

In ~/genymotion-log/Google Nexus 6<...>-logcat.txt, I see the following:

```
05-15 23:50:14.379 D/OpenGLRenderer(  620): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-15 23:50:14.380 D/Atlas   (  620): Validating map...
05-15 23:50:14.429 I/OpenGLRenderer(  620): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-15 23:50:14.429 D/        (  620): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf31ca40, tid 1876
05-15 23:50:14.463 D/OpenGLRenderer(  620): Enabling debug mode 0
05-15 23:50:14.489 W/EGL_emulation(  620): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-15 23:50:14.490 W/OpenGLRenderer(  620): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e45dfc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-15 23:50:14.490 W/EGL_emulation(  941): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-15 23:50:14.490 W/OpenGLRenderer(  941): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb43e44a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-15 23:50:14.952 I/ActivityManager(  620): Killing 1492:com.android.onetimeinitializer/u0a10 (adj 15): empty #17
05-15 23:50:15.219 W/OpenGLRenderer(  941): Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
05-15 23:50:15.440 W/ResourceType(  724): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
05-15 23:50:15.442 W/PackageManager(  724): Failure retrieving resources for com.bidsmart: Resource ID #0x0
05-15 23:50:18.400 W/AudioTrack(  620): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
05-15 23:50:18.424 I/Process ( 1805): Sending signal. PID: 1805 SIG: 9
05-15 23:50:18.463 D/OpenGLRenderer(  620): endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa1a6f780 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xaf3be470
05-15 23:50:18.468 I/ActivityManager(  620): Process com.bidsmart (pid 1805) has died
05-15 23:50:18.472 W/InputMethodManagerService(  620): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1805 uid 10061
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect a port in your App @Nathan Hyland.

Comment: Not sure what that means, really. A physical port? To be clear, the app works until you hit one of the components, which has a few more nested.

Comment: Yes@ Nathan Hyland

Comment: Nope. , just showing a scroll view.

Comment: When you debugging an android app, you can use command 'adb logcat' to see logs from native application layer, it's useful when locating problem

Comment: Thanks, @Xeijp. That helped. The line I found that helped me out was this:
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2470012 byte allocation with 48508 free bytes and 47KB until OOM`
It's saying I'm adding too many images.. I'm only adding 12 png/jpeg files to the app. My guess is they're all pushing multiple times, crashing the application.

Answer (score 0):

No fix, but the reason is I'm pushing too much data from the server to the client. Once I ran adb logcat, I got this:

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2470012 byte allocation with 48508 free bytes and 47KB until OOM`.

Turns out I'm pushing my images over and over to the client until it breaks. iOS can handle it but RN can't.

Link to StackOverflow related thread: [Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)