# My function cant save the photo in the phone gallery. he save the photo in DCIM

Tags: java, android, camera

here is the function who save the photo. I want to put the picture in the gallery.

```
public File getOutputMediaFile() {
            File dir2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "dentafy");
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
            String filename = File.separator + "2IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            Log.d("getOutMediaFile", filename);
            File c = new File(dir2.getPath(), filename);
            filepath = filename;
            picturepath();


            return c;

        }

        public String picturepath( )
        {
            return filepath;
        }
```

Comment: Post your logcat too.

Comment: what a fat activity you have !!

Comment: If i just modify the DIRECTORY the picture doesn`t save it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your log (I removed irrelevant lines):

```
06-28 13:17:12.165 17307-17307/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
06-28 13:17:12.195 17307-17307/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10802K, 2% free 58270K/59144K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
06-28 13:44:21.398 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy D/Activity: performCreate Call debug elastic valuetrue
06-28 13:44:21.458 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy time:156085873
06-28 13:44:22.619 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy D/valoare este %@: file:///file%3A/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy/files/Pictures/JPEG_20160628_134421_558130986.jpg
06-28 13:44:22.619 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy D/valoare 2 este %@: file:///file%3A/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy/files/Pictures/JPEG_20160628_134421_558130986.jpg
06-28 13:44:23.140 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 198(22KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 6% free, 107MB/115MB, paused 732us total 10.467ms
06-28 13:44:23.160 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1281(108KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 12% free, 107MB/123MB, paused 732us total 16.082ms
06-28 13:44:23.190 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 16(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 107MB/123MB, paused 732us total 30.761ms
06-28 13:44:23.190 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 36MB allocation
06-28 13:44:23.210 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 12% free, 107MB/123MB, paused 610us total 22.705ms
06-28 13:44:23.210 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 38340876 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 20MB until OOM"
06-28 13:44:23.210 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
06-28 13:44:23.210 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-28 13:44:23.220 24638-24638/com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy, PID: 24638
                                                                                java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 38340876 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 20MB until OOM
                                                                                    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:752)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:728)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:477)
                                                                                    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:515)
                                                                                    at com.example.newrosoft1.dentafy.PictureConfirmation.onCreate(PictureConfirmation.java:411)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

The difference between front- and rear- cameras is that the picture taken by the latter is much larger, and it is impossible to convert it at full scale into Bitmap to display it in ImageView: you cross the app memory limit. You can increase the amount of memory allowed for your app, but better - reduce the size of the bitmap. Here you have two alternatives: set picture size for the rear camera to be smaller (preferably fit the size of the image view), or scale the bitmap down in `decodeFile()`.

Comment: Can you give me a code fragment with that changes please?

Comment: please look up the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio) - it has very good answers

Comment: man can you help me a little?? I have a fragment with camera and i can`t save the photo in the gallery. I have a function who take the last picture which was made.

Comment: You are always welcome to post  a question on SO. Is there something more specific that I can help you?

Comment: I want to save my photo in gallery, dirrectly... not in another file

Comment: I solve the problem with the memorry.

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" in manifest solve it

Comment: You are abusing SO by changing the question. You can always ask a new question. It's free. Now, regarding saving to gallery, see http://junjunguo.com/articles/android-take-photo-show-in-list-view/