# Android: Error while capturing image from camera intent

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-camera-intent

After capturing image from camera the app stops with the errors shown in the logcat.I think this is related with the size of the image captured.Do i need to compress image before uploading it to server.
Here is the relevant code

```
private void openCameraIntent() {

    createImageFile();
    Utils.getInstance().openCamera(this,profileImageFile);
}

private void createImageFile() {

    try{

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        profileImageFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/StoredImages/"+"img" + timeStamp + ".jpeg";
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

openCamera Method

```
public void openCamera(Fragment fragment,String mediaFile) {

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/StoredImages/");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
    }
    try{
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri camCapfileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mediaFile));
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, camCapfileUri);
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, StringConstants.CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

onActivityResult

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == StringConstants.CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE &&
            resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        onCameraImageCapture();
    }else if(requestCode == StringConstants.PERMISSION_REQUESTCODE_GALLERY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        onGalleryImageSelected(data);
    }
}
```

after image is captured it is converted into String like this

```
private void onCameraImageCapture() {

    profileBitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(profileImageFile);
    String x = Utils.getInstance().encodeToBase64(profileBitMap,Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100);
    uploadProfileImage();

}

public static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image, Bitmap.CompressFormat compressFormat, int quality) {

    try{

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(compressFormat, quality, byteArrayOS);
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and the stringis sent as a parameter to our server to save it.But it shows following error[image]

Comment: check this out : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio

Comment: `and the following message is displayed`. You are not even mentioning the error. And logcats should be posted as text. Not as an image.

Comment: Pretty bad idea to fiddle aroud with Bitmaps and base64 to upload a jpg file. It can easily lead to out of memory as the bitmap will take ten times as much memory as the jpg. You probably let the bitmap compress back to jpg too. Which we dont know for sure as `compressFormat` is unknown.

Comment: follow this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity

Comment: @Gaurav. There is nothing there that uploads an image file.

Comment: @greenapps: I used BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();options.inSampleSize = 8; and its working fine.Is it a proper way?

Comment: That is you who decides. Do you want to upload that jpg file or do you want to upload a resized -smaller- image? If you want to resize the code is ok. If you want to upload the original jpg file then do not fiddle around with converting to Bitmap first.

Comment: @greenapps:ok .Thanks a lot..