# Android : Out of memory exception while scrolling GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, out-of-memory, android-gridview

I have created a `GridView` as following

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="application.example.com.fragment_practice.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/image_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="@dimen/grid_view_width"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/dp_10" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Following is my `MainActivity.java` class

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
      gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
   }
}
```

Following is `ImageAdapter.java` class

```
   public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180, 180));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
        }
        else
        {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.sample_1, R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3, R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5, R.drawable.sample_6,
            R.drawable.sample_7, R.drawable.sample_8,
            R.drawable.sample_13, R.drawable.sample_9,
            R.drawable.sample_10, R.drawable.sample_11,
            R.drawable.sample_12, R.drawable.sample_13,
            R.drawable.sample_14, R.drawable.sample_16,
            R.drawable.sample_16, R.drawable.sample_17,
            R.drawable.sample_18, R.drawable.sample_19,
            R.drawable.sample_20, R.drawable.sample_21,
            R.drawable.sample_22, R.drawable.sample_23
    };
}
```

Every thing is working perfect until I scroll.
Following is the Exception I am getting on scrolling the `GridView` 3-4 time up and down.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: mai
>   Process: application.example.com.fragment_practice, PID: 18917
>                                                                                           java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4915212 byte
>   allocation with 2666656 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
>                                                                                               at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:856)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:675)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:2230)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:4284)
>                                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:4158)
>                                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2043)
>                                                                                               at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:2025)
>                                                                                               at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:464)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:827)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:434)
>                                                                                               at
>   application.example.com.fragment_practice.ImageAdapter.getView(ImageAdapter.java:48)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2937)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1463)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:366)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.GridView.fillUp(GridView.java:407)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.GridView.fillGap(GridView.java:282)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:7307)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:4400)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:5796)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:5624)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:10011)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2833)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2504)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:5561)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2519)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2519)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2519)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2519)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2519)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2519)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2519)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2844)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2519)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2840)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1853)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3061)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:63)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2801)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10246)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5447)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5283)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4721)
>                                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.

**EDIT 1 :** Anyone please explain why I am getting this issue on scrolling 3-4 time up and down  grid view not on loading ?

Comment: Images size is large thats why this error coming

Comment: if image is large then it should give the exception while creating the grid view

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio

Comment: hey I am not dealing with bitmap.. I am using simple .png images of some 54 kb

Comment: I think that you should try to use the adapter holder pattern. I'll try to write an answer

Comment: that would be very helpful to me. Please Answer..

Comment: @MKY you are using almost 4.9MB of images.please look at this line `Failed to allocate a 4915212 byte allocation with 2666656 free bytes`

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya Hey I am not using 4 MB..when I am scrolling then it getting increase.. I think there may be every time when I scroll some memory  allocated and not getting destroyed...I am not sure but like this something is going one..that is why I am asking for explanation. why i am getting this exception on 3-4 time scrolling not on one time scrolling

Comment: @MKY try to put this line `imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position])` inside `if (convertView == null) {}`

Comment: tried but. It is not giving that exception but on each and every scroll it is changing the image position

Comment: You should precise that you are using this tuto: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

 Are you using the same picture as provided in this guide ? If yes then your error comes from somewhere else because this guide will work.

Comment: @ThomasRoulin Yes I have used that tutorial but that doesn't matter because I have given all code here itself. N yes I am using different image than provided in that example, Just increase the number of images you will get same error there also.

Comment: @ThomasRoulin suppose i want to use 100 images then what will happen..there will be some way

Comment: Then, you should try the @piyukataria answer. But increase the heap size **only** if the first doesn't work.

Comment: where did you put R.drawable.sample_1 and other images?

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro in  res/drawable-hdpi folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a library called  [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), to use this library add the followings in your gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

And then create a folder named `drawable-nodpi` inside your res folder . Put all of your images there and don't forget to remove your images from `drawable-hdpi` and other drawable folder . Make sure images only exist in `drawable-nodpi` folder. Then  instead of `imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);` this , do the following

```
Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(mThumbIds[position])
     .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
     .skipMemoryCache( true )
     .int‌​o(imageView);
```

Let me know if it works .

Comment: will try and let you know

Comment: hey it is working as expected but when ever i start scrolling i am getting thie warning on console

application.example.com.fragment_practice W/Bitmap: Called reconfigure on a bitmap that is in use! This may cause graphical corruption!

Comment: one more explanation I need why are you telling to create folder name `drawable-nodpi` as it is working fine with `drawable-hdpi`? is there any reason ?

Comment: for bitmap you can try asBitmap()‌  property to glide  like Glide.with(mContext)
     .load(mThumbIds[position])
     .asBitmap()‌ 
     .diskCacheStrategy( DiskCacheStrategy.NONE )
     .skipMemoryCache( true )
     .int‌​o(imageView);
And yes there is a reason for using drawable-nodpi, the out of memory error occurred because of sampling the image to device size. by using drawable-nodpi you stop scaling according to device dpi.

Comment: I accepted your answer but adding asBitmap() din't  solve that warning

Answer (score 3):

Use Glide to load images:-

Add dependency in your gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Load Images:-

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(mThumbIds[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder).into(imageView);
```

If this will not work try this,
Add in your app's build.gradle inside android block

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    jumboMode = true
}
```