# How to solve the Fragment Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

Below is my code.

**MainActivity.java** code below:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.loginFrame, new LoginFragment()).commit();

    }
}
```

**Fragment Activity** .java code which is called in **MainActivity.java**

```
  public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
        EditText emailEt,passwordEt;
        String email,password;
        Button login,signup;
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootview = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            emailEt=(EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.emailEt);
            passwordEt=(EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.passEt);
            login=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
            signup=(Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.signupBtn);

            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    email=emailEt.getText().toString();
                    password=passwordEt.getText().toString();

                    if(email.length()==0){
                        emailEt.requestFocus();
                        emailEt.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                    }else if(password.length()==0){
                        passwordEt.requestFocus();
                        passwordEt.setError("FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY");
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Validation Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),Options_class.class);
                        startActivity(in);
                    }
                }
            });

            signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Signup.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return rootview;
        }
    }
```

Error **logcat** of code which show oncreate() Error in mainclass

> t dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1152)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:724)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:575)
>                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:854)
>                                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:167)
>                                                                                  at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:155)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1021)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1080)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                                  at com.example.nirmit.demo_frg.Login.onCreate(Login.java:13)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Can any body help me to solve this problem of logcat in mainActivity and fragment code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio

Answer (score 1):

Modify this line

```
View rootview = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

into this

```
   View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
```

Comment: again same problem

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.nirmit.demo_frg, PID: 18536
                                                                             java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 178787560 byte allocation with 16768488 free bytes and 154MB until OOM

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            fragment = new LoginFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.loginFrame, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                //initToolbar();
            }


        }
    }
```

And

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
    View rootview;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(your_layout, null);


        return rootview;
    }
}
```