# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView

Tags: android, layout, android-inflate

I'm getting below error in my xml file of android project.

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView

I've seen the [this solution but can't understand/ it doesn't in my project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio) Is there any problem with the xml file? Or do I need to work on activity file?

I'm getting the error while adding a custom navigation drawer.

Here is the error

```
09-14 04:23:53.841 22880-22880/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :info.androidhive.navigationdrawer
09-14 04:23:53.851 22880-22880/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.navigationdrawer, PID: 22880
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.navigationdrawer/info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.SplashScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1978)
at info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:14)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1978) 
at info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:14) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
```

Here is my activity file:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        Thread myThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

Here is my xml file of splash screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.SplashScreen">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ist_logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="IST LIBRARY"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Android Application"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="of"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Library Management of IST"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is nothing more in the stack trace, below what you have posted?

Comment: there are some other issues. But for simplicity I posted this

Answer (score 1):

Stack trace may be misleading. There might be a problem with your drawable. Try a different `@drawable` and see if it works.

Comment: thank you. that problem is solved, but now in next activity I got this error:
Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

```
android:src="@drawable/ist_logo
```

in this line change the picture you're using and use another smaller picture in png format