# Error requires 'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' or grantUriPermission()

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

**I'm reading file from sd card but getting above error though i have mentioned all external storage permission in manifest but still getting above error.**

This is my logcat:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.murarilal.listview/com.example.murarilal.listview.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/audio/media from pid=12518, uid=10087
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri
>   content://media/external/audio/media from pid=12518, uid=10087
>   requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>                                                                                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
>                                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:530)
>                                                                                               at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:472)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.example.murarilal.listview.MainActivity.getMusic(MainActivity.java:57)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.example.murarilal.listview.MainActivity.doStuff(MainActivity.java:77)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.example.murarilal.listview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
>                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

**Note : I am reading files from sdcard. I think the error is in getMusic() function withe the cursor. Please help me with this.**

**MainActivity Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);

            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST);

            }
        } else {
            doStuff();
        }

    }

    public void getMusic()
    {
        ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        Uri songUri =MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor songCursor=contentResolver.query(songUri,null,null,null,null);
        {
            if(songCursor!=null && songCursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                int songTitle=songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                int songArtist=songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                do{
                    String currentTitle=songCursor.getString(songTitle);
                    String currentArtist=songCursor.getString(songArtist);
                    arrayList.add(currentTitle +"\n"+currentArtist);

                }while (songCursor.moveToFirst());

            }
        }
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        getMusic();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode, String[] permissions,int[] grantResults){
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    {
                        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            doStuff();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "no permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }

                    }
                    return;
                }
        }
    }



}
```

Anyhelp would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is  :

You are checking that if `permission` is not `Denied` than request permission and if it denied than `doStuff()` which is totally opposite of what you want to do .

You should check if it is not `Granted` than request permission and if is granted than `doStuff()`

Change your code if condition as :

From

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
```

To

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

Comment: it worked,but  showing blank actvity.

Comment: Now whats the issue ? debug in your Music method

Comment: Failed to allocate a 24613612 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 19MB until OOM. this the error i m getting

Comment: Thats the diff question. It is OutOfMemory Error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio

Comment: But I think your this question has been answered