# what is the best way to save memory while going back and forth between different activities that use bitmaps

Tags: java, android

This application has MainActivity and it uses about 20 bitmaps. It works pretty fine but when I start an intent to another activity and then go back to the MainActivity, it crashes because of memory problem. It gives this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2052108 byte allocation with 1629176 free bytes and 1590KB until OOM
```

I have also used these in the manifest

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

What would be the best method to be able to switch between Activities without using more memory? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Comment: you can consider using glide or picasso to handle the bitmap caching. this prevents the bitmap from loading multiple times and reuse bitmaps that's already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

you just recycle bitmap when there is no longer in used

```
myBitmap.recycle();
```