# Android OOM Error, Loading multiple images

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I was [looking at this answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio), however it didn't really fix my problem.

For some reason the `manifest.xml` doesn't overwrite my changes, even though I deleted my `build` folder.

I am trying to load up 5 images on the screen, however even after optimizing them; they still run out of memory.

I was watching a [video that teaches image scaling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTlJT2b5dd4). It did solved a small portion of my problem. I am able to load my background image, however I wasn't able to load my other 4 images.

How can I optimize more efficiently? I was watching this video regards [Bitmap optimization by Android](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/index.html), however I didn't understand much from it.

Here is my source code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.cliente.myapplication;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final float BYTES_PER_PX = 4.0f;
    ImageView backgroundImage, upImage, downImage, leftImage, alertImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background_image);
        loadImage(backgroundImage, R.drawable.background);

        upImage = findViewById(R.id.up_arrow_image);
        loadImage(upImage, R.drawable.up);

        downImage = findViewById(R.id.down_arrow_image);
        loadImage(downImage, R.drawable.down);

        leftImage = findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_image);
        loadImage(leftImage, R.drawable.left);

        alertImage = findViewById(R.id.alert_image);
        loadImage(alertImage, R.drawable.alert);

    }

    private void loadImage(ImageView image, int imgSrc) {
        if (readBitmapInfo() > MemUtils.megabytesFree()) {
            subSampleImage(image, 32);
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(imgSrc);
        }
    }

    private float readBitmapInfo() {
        final Resources res = this.getResources();
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background, options);
        final float imageHeight = options.outHeight;
        final float imageWidth = options.outWidth;

        return imageWidth * imageHeight * BYTES_PER_PX / MemUtils.BYTES_IN_MB;
    }

    private void subSampleImage(ImageView image, int powerOf2) {
        if (powerOf2 < 1 || powerOf2 > 2) {
            return;
        }

        final Resources res = this.getResources();
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = powerOf2;
        final Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background, options);
        image.setImageBitmap(map);
    }

}
```

MemUtils.java

```
package com.example.cliente.myapplication;

public class MemUtils {
    public static final float BYTES_IN_MB = 1024.0f * 1024.0f;

    public static float megabytesFree() {
        final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final float bytesUsed = rt.totalMemory();
        final float mbUsed = bytesUsed / BYTES_IN_MB;
        final float mbFree = megabytesAvailable() - mbUsed;
        return mbFree;
    }

    public static float megabytesAvailable() {
        final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        final float bytesAvailable = rt.maxMemory();
        return bytesAvailable / BYTES_IN_MB;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use Picasso or Fresco and save yourself the math and calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had **2 errors** to begin with.

- OOM (out of memory) exception, thanks too @Chisko, I used a library called `Picasso` to solve my problem.
- Another issue was `Canvas: trying to draw too large...` problem. Which I needed to move my images from `drawable-mdpi` to `drawable-xxhdpi`.

Here is the solution to my problem:

```
package com.example.cliente.myapplication;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView backgroundImage, upImage, downImage, leftImage, alertImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background_image);
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.background).into(backgroundImage);

        upImage = findViewById(R.id.up_arrow_image);
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.up).into(upImage);

        downImage = findViewById(R.id.down_arrow_image);
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.down).into(downImage);

        leftImage = findViewById(R.id.left_arrow_image);
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.left).into(leftImage);

        alertImage = findViewById(R.id.alert_image);
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.alert).into(alertImage);
    }
}
```