# OutOfMemoryError when using animation list

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using an animation in my splash screen. While the splash is shown the application does some preparations in the background like login.

The animation is created by using animation list as such:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00001" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00002" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00003" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00004" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00005" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00006" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00007" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00008" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00009" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00010" android:duration="35" />
    .
    .
    .
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00069" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/part_00070" android:duration="35" />

</animation-list>
```

This is my splash activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#000">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_animation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, to start the animation I do the following in onCreate method:

```
ImageView rocketImage;
AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;
rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_animation);
rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.movie);
rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
rocketAnimation.start();
```

However, after I run the application 3-4 times it crashes and says:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4665612 byte
>   allocation with 700512 free bytes and 684KB until OOM

What can I overcome this issue?

Comment: use android:largeHeap="true" in manifest file

Comment: I tried it as well, and it didn't help.

Comment: try this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245018/7319704

Comment: probably your images are too large

Comment: You should decrease your image to a lower quality, because animation will display fast so you don't need a high quality image, just smooth animation is better.

Comment: You can use "tiny png" for compressing images

Answer (score 0):

Where are your images placed in drawable or drawable-hdpi?

Comment: They are placed in drawable.

Comment: Just put them in drawable-hdpi and add  Add hardwareAccelerated & largeHeap under application AndroidManifest.xml like this:

    

`<application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:largeHeap="true"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

And let me know if it works

Comment: @Keselme Put the images in drawable-nodpi folder. So that images are not being resized and forcing oom. Also optimize your images to reduce file size. There are lots of online tools for that.

Comment: No problems. Always a pleasure. You can make it as an accepted answer so others can know as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in manifest file :-

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</application>
```