# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 2359308 byte allocation with 224532 free bytes and 219KB until OOM

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-imageview

Error in my Login Page. After I declared in Manifest file Application Tag:

```
<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"/>
```

After I created another Activity Used in `Imageview` also give same error. How to avoid this error from my app? How this error occurred and what is the solution?Below `xml` file take another Eight `imagview`. Its Same implement as the first two `imageview`. So, I was not display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context="com.zala.sanklappreschool.Advertisement">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/adv_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true">


        <com.zala.sanklappreschool.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/adv_view_pager_indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <!--  <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tvreg"/>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tvBranch"/>

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/tvyer"/>-->


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/rlHome"
                    android:layout_weight="0.65"
                    android:background="@color/red">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:id="@+id/imgHome"
                            android:tint="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Home"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imgHome"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.65"
                    android:background="@color/yellow_dark"
                    android:id="@+id/rlAbout">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_about"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:id="@+id/imgAbout"
                            android:tint="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="About Us"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imgAbout"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:textSize="14sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>     
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>         
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to `File-->Invalidate cache/Restart`.

Comment: what have you done in your java code?

Comment: You might like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32244851/3166697).