# How to restrict a user to pick only few images from the gallery?

Tags: java, android

when I get many images from gallery my `application` crashed 
Help me to pick at least 10 images from gallery

I use this Code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),
                          PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE);
```

error:

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: android.itgdeveloper.com.qainshpection, PID: 7514
>     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 19660812 byte allocation with 967032 free bytes and 944KB until OOM
>         at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>         at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>         at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
>         at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
>         at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)
>         at android.itgdeveloper.com.qainshpection.core.ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(ImageHelper.java:17)
>         at android.itgdeveloper.com.qainshpection.Model.KIK_ImageAdapter.getView(KIK_ImageAdapter.java:108)
>         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2491)
>         at android.widget.GridView.makeAndAddView(GridView.java:1444)
>         at android.widget.GridView.makeRow(GridView.java:371)
>         at android.widget.GridView.fillDown(GridView.java:312)
>         at android.widget.GridView.fillFromTop(GridView.java:447)
>         at android.widget.GridView.layoutChildren(GridView.java:1288)
>         at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2249)
>         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17838)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5754)
> ```

Comment: But, what have you tried? **SHOW US SOME CODE!**

Comment: you have some problem with your code. Since you didn't show neither code nor crash log - good luck fixing it on your own.

Comment: Your question and your description don't match. Your question (title) claims you want to set a MAXIMAL number of selections, your description points to a MINIMAL number of selections.

Comment: use 3rd lib for image picker

Comment: have a look for the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio

Comment: I would recommend using https://github.com/zhihu/Matisse

Comment: you don't have enough RAM to load all images. Pre-scale them before loading

Comment: add `android:largeHeap="true"` in `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` file