# Failed to allocate a 83070912 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 34MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 525798800, growth limit 536870912

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am really stuck. I am familiar in Java and Android development but i do not have any experience with databases.

```
public ArrayList<String> getIstilah(int dicType){
    String tableName = getTableName(dicType);
    String q = "SELECT * FROM "+tableName;
    Cursor result = sDB.rawQuery(q, null);

    ArrayList<String> source = new ArrayList<>();
    while (result.moveToFirst()){
        source.add(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_JUDUL)));// line 97
    }
    return source;
}
```

> 2019-10-31 16:36:16.881 2267-2267/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
>   2019-10-31 16:36:16.884 2267-2267/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
>   2019-10-31 16:36:42.843 2267-2267/id.AntBeeDev.ContohKamus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: id.AntBeeDev.ContohKamus, PID: 2267
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 83070912 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 34MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 525798768, growth limit 536870912
>           at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3139)
>           at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3109)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:275)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:249)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:241)
>           at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:467)
>           at id.AntBeeDev.ContohKamus.DBHelper.getIstilah(DBHelper.java:97)
>           at id.AntBeeDev.ContohKamus.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:105)
>           at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3568)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:325)
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2830)
>           at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:455)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:56)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7078)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the Cursor and move to the first row add the data to the array then move to the first row and add the data FOREVER (as long as 1 or more rows have been extracted by the query).

You should use **moveToNext** rather than **moveToFirst** (which will move to the First row initially, as the cursor is initially positioned at **before the first row** *(position -1)*) e.g. :-

```
while (result.moveToNext()){
    source.add(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_JUDUL)));// line 97
}
result.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< SHOULD ALWAYS CLOSE CURSORS WHEN DONE WITH THEM
return source;
```