# How to unload an image displayed on an Image object to free up memory?

Tags: android, image, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms Android Project that displays images one after another on a press of a button. My current test device is an HTC Nexus 9 and apparently, due to its limited specs, i get below error when trying to load my 17th image:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11059212 byte allocation with 8286168 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:771)
    at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:525)
    at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:455)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
    at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
    at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.n_onClick(Native Method)
    at crc64ee486da937c010f4.ButtonRenderer.onClick(ButtonRenderer.java:104)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6229)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

I tried setting the `Java Max Heap Size` to `1G` under `.Android > Properties > Android Options > Advanced` but nothing changed.
[image]

I found a [potential solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32245018/7825830) but apparently, its for Java based Android App and i don't know where to find a similar manifest file on Xamarin.Forms` Android Project.

Below is a snippet of my code using the simplest MVVM implementation:

**.xaml**

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}"
       WidthRequest="960"
       HeightRequest="720" />
       

<!--#region Page1 Controls-->
<Button Command="{Binding Page1DhcpIconCommand}"
        IsVisible="{Binding Page1ControlVisible}"
        BackgroundColor="{Binding Page1ControlColor}"
        Opacity="0.25"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="57"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="679"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="46"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="37" />
<!--#endregion-->

<!--#region Page2 Controls-->
<Button Command="{Binding Page2RolesCommand}"
        IsVisible="{Binding Page2ControlVisible}"
        BackgroundColor="{Binding Page2ControlColor}"
        Opacity="0.25"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="24"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="85"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="46"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="15" />
<!--#endregion-->

<!--#region Page3 Controls-->
<Button Command="{Binding Page3AddRolesCommand}"
        IsVisible="{Binding Page3ControlVisible}"
        BackgroundColor="{Binding Page3ControlColor}"
        Opacity="0.25"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="720"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="199"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="71"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="21" />
<!--#endregion-->
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
#region Backing Fields
string imgSource;

bool page1ControlVisible;
string page1ControlColor;

bool page2ControlVisible;
string page2ControlColor;

bool page3ControlVisible;
string page3ControlColor;
#endregion
#region Private Variables
private readonly bool _transparentOverride;
#endregion
#region Public Properties
public string ImgSource
{
    get => imgSource;
    set => SetProperty(ref imgSource, value);
}

#region Page1 Properties & Commands
public bool Page1ControlVisible
{
    get => page1ControlVisible;
    set => SetProperty(ref page1ControlVisible, value);
}
public string Page1ControlColor
{
    get => page1ControlColor;
    set => SetProperty(ref page1ControlColor, value);
}

public Command Page1DhcpIconCommand { get; }
#endregion

#region Page2 Properties & Commands
public bool Page2ControlVisible
{
    get => page2ControlVisible;
    set => SetProperty(ref page2ControlVisible, value);
}
public string Page2ControlColor
{
    get => page2ControlColor;
    set => SetProperty(ref page2ControlColor, value);
}

public Command Page2RolesCommand { get; }
#endregion

#region Page3 Properties & Commands
public bool Page3ControlVisible
{
    get => page3ControlVisible;
    set => SetProperty(ref page3ControlVisible, value);
}
public string Page3ControlColor
{
    get => page3ControlColor;
    set => SetProperty(ref page3ControlColor, value);
}

public Command Page3AddRolesCommand { get; }
#endregion
#endregion


public DHCPConfigurationViewModel()
{
    _transparentOverride = true;

    ImgSource = "img_dhcp_config_01.jpg";

    #region Page1 Properties & Commands
    Page1ControlVisible = true;
    Page1ControlColor = _transparentOverride ? "Transparent" : "Red";

    Page1DhcpIconCommand = new Command(Page1DhcpIcon);
    #endregion

    #region Page2 Properties & Commands
    Page2ControlVisible = false;
    Page2ControlColor = _transparentOverride ? "Transparent" : "Orange";

    Page2RolesCommand = new Command(Page2Roles);
    #endregion

    #region Page3 Properties & Commands
    Page3ControlVisible = false;
    Page3ControlColor = _transparentOverride ? "Transparent" : "Yellow";

    Page3AddRolesCommand = new Command(Page3AddRoles);
    #endregion
}

private void Page1DhcpIcon()
{
    ImgSource = "img_dhcp_config_02.jpg";

    Page1ControlVisible = false;
    Page2ControlVisible = true;
}

private void Page2Roles()
{
    ImgSource = "img_dhcp_config_03.jpg";

    Page2ControlVisible = false;
    Page3ControlVisible = true;
}

private void Page3AddRoles()
{
    ImgSource = "img_dhcp_config_04.jpg";

    Page3ControlVisible = false;
    Page4ControlVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: the manifest file is in the Properties folder of the Android project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you can check document [Improve Xamarin.Forms App Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance).

Specially part: [Optimize image resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance#optimize-image-resources):

> Displaying image resources can greatly increase an application's
> memory footprint. Therefore, they should only be created when required
> and should be released as soon as the application no longer requires
> them. For example, if an application is displaying an image by reading
> its data from a stream, ensure that stream is created only when it's
> required, and ensure that the stream is released when it's no longer
> required. This can be achieved by creating the stream when the page is
> created, or when the Page.Appearing event fires, and then disposing of
> the stream when the Page.Disappearing event fires.

When downloading an image for display with the [ImageSource.FromUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.imagesource.fromuri?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_ImageSource_FromUri_System_Uri_) method, cache the downloaded image by ensuring that the [UriImageSource.CachingEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.uriimagesource.cachingenabled?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_UriImageSource_CachingEnabled) property is set to `true`.

You can also try nuget [Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms),which is a xamarin Library to load images quickly and easily on Xamarin.Forms.
For more details,please check:https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading .

Comment: Hi, as i understand it. Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms and the Documentation caters to images sourced from a `Uri`. However, my images are local resources stored on the `.Android > Resources > Drawable` folder.

I'd like to give the Image from stream a try, but how can this be achieved (and disposed once no longer needed) via MVVM Pattern?

Comment: Nuget `Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms` could also been used for  local resources. You can also check the sample code here:https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/tree/master/samples .