# Android Out of memory error with newNonMovableArray in loading Drawable

Tags: android

I've got a strange (for me) "Out of memory" error in my app.:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.fhkiel.socialrobotcms, PID: 5029
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 136887708 byte allocation with 3292628 free bytes and 123MB until OOM
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:651)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:486)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1085)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2867)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2756)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:73)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:206)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:125)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1566)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1617)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreateView(Fragment.java:1968)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2777)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3020)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:551)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:262)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:478)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:246)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1245)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6355)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2540)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1499)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5875)
    at jav
```

here the log ends. For me the errors semms to happen, if the system loads a Drwable resource. But besides a 160kb big png, if have only vector assets.

Even this error only happens on a real device, not in the emulator with the same specs.
Also there are around 350MB of free memory. While the

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

option fixes the problems (the urgly way), it seems to have to do with something on the heap.
therefore the error also happens, if the doesn nothing. Just displaying one empty fragment.

Any ideas how to dig deeper into the problem?

best regards.

Comment: Please check this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio#answer-32245018)

Comment: Sure, i try the solutions and will report. Even i have not bitmaps. This can still happen with vector graphics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Umesh for reminding me for the question about the working solution:

[Android:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 23970828 byte allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 2MB until OOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244851/androidjava-lang-outofmemoryerror-failed-to-allocate-a-23970828-byte-allocatio#answer-32245018)

although i am not using a bitmap, all binary graphics must be include into drawable-xhdpi/ directory (or larger). So although I am not loading aný bitmap data (as kind of bmp files), the UI loads a binary image. Therefore it must pu put into the correct diectory, dependin its size (where binary images are always xhdpi or above).